# How to prevent JSONObject from json.jar converts decimal numbers string into double

Tags: java, json, double, org.json

Using `JSONObject` to read a json response from a server. The server returns some decimal number. Normal numbers are not a problem to but the problem occurs when there is decimal number of form `0.00068`. Numbers like `0.00068` are automatically stored into `Double` object and when an attempt is made to retrieve such number returns "computerized scientific notation" of the number , that is 6.8E4 even if the number accessed as double by `getDouble(index)` method or as String with `getString(index)` method.

Have tried this way of converting double value to string but have have eliminated this tecinique as there is some positve rounding added when `Double` converted to `BigDecimal`. This can be eliminated by rounding set while scaling to `BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING`. But I don't want any scaling and want with the original values as the actual value is a small decimal number and the server guarantees the number wont exceed 6 digit after the decimal point.

```
BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal(new Double(0.00680));

System.out.println(big.toPlainString()); //0.006799999999999999621136392846665330580435693264007568359375

System.out.println(big.setScale(15, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN)); //0.006799999999999
```

Can there be some way to get actual string value of Double that is a number 0.00680 without scaling, or can we prevent `JSONObject` interpreting numbers in to their respective numeric classes.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: There are two JSON Java libraries that I know of, have a class called JSONObject. The org.json.* and the net.sf.json.*. Which one you are talking about?

Comment: I am using org.json.* or org.json.JSONObject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unrelated to the JSON library you use, you should not use the [BigDecimal constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) taking a double parameter, since that uses the exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value

Instead, use the static `valueOf` method since that uses the string value of the double and thus rounds correctly.

> When a double must be used as a source for a BigDecimal, note that this constructor provides an exact conversion; it does not give the same result as converting the double to a String using the `Double.toString(double)` method and then using the `BigDecimal(String)` constructor. To get that result, use the static `valueOf(double)` method.

However, for very large or small numbers the parsing to a double might already have introduced rounding errors, in that case the only solution would be to use a different JSON library that supports parsing numbers as BigDecimals.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer but valueOf(double) performs some default rounding System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(new Double("-0.00066359999")).toPlainString()); //-0.000006636 so not a complete solution, also this question is related to JSON as I was searching a way to parse json document avoiding JSONObject to apply default Objects to String text in the document , where I want to handle these values as plain string.

Comment: With java 1.6.0_26 that prints "-0.00066359999" on my computer, so I don't see any rounding. Still, it would be better to switch to another JSON parser that allows parsing numbers as BigDecimals.

Comment: The rounding mechanism completely depends on number of digits before the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

In org.json.JSONObject class comment out lines in method stringToValue(String string)

```
    /*
     * If it might be a number, try converting it. If a number cannot be
     * produced, then the value will just be a string.
     */

    char initial = string.charAt(0);
    if ((initial >= '0' && initial <= '9') || initial == '-') {
        try {
            // if we want full Big Number support this block can be replaced with:
            // return stringToNumber(string);
            if (isDecimalNotation(string)) {
                Double d = Double.valueOf(string);
                if (!d.isInfinite() && !d.isNaN()) {
                    return d;
                }
            } else {
                Long myLong = Long.valueOf(string);
                if (string.equals(myLong.toString())) {
                    if (myLong.longValue() == myLong.intValue()) {
                        return Integer.valueOf(myLong.intValue());
                    }
                    return myLong;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }
```