# org.json.JSONObject messing with data

Tags: java

I got a different type of numbers in my json string. So parsing this numbers with JSONObject leads to `3.7E-4`-like representation of this numbers. I prefer to see numbers as a `string`. What to do? How to prevent such conversion?

```
{"data":
    {"number1":0.0004,
     "number2":0.00038,
     "number3":0.00037
}}
```

Comment: What library are you using to parse JSON with, Jackson?

Comment: Read article again, please.

Comment: [Which one](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=*.JSONObject)

Comment: Yes. org.json.JSONObject Sorry didn't know that.

Comment: What does the JSON look like?  If the JSON (before parsing) contains `"key":"0.00037"` then that's a string.  If it contains `"key":0.00037` then that's a number, and what you're getting is correct.

Comment: Ok, now i get it. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, those are numbers -- will come through as Number objects after parsing.  You can, of course, format them differently with an appropriate formatting operation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, create a string before putting your number to JSON.

or

```
int number = 0;
json.put(number + "");
```

Can you give an example number, not represented like above?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is some limitation of this particular json library. As a workaround, you could convert parsed values to BigDecimal and use it, unless the double conversion does not lose precision significantly.

For more details read this: [How to prevent JSONObject from json.jar converts decimal numbers string into double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710450/how-to-prevent-jsonobject-from-json-jar-converts-decimal-numbers-string-into-dou)